# Rails, Coffee, jQuery - removeAttr not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I've been trying to get this code to work and everything seems correct but I can't get attr - "disabled" to be removed. The button disables initially but then when the fields are populated the "else" part does not fire. I thought this should execute after every "change", but it appears to not loop through the inputs correctly.

static_pages.js.coffee---

```
jQuery ->
  $("#gradesModal :input").on('keypress', ->
      empty = false
      $("#gradesModal :input").each ->
        empty = true if $(this).val() is ""
        if empty
          $("#add-grade").attr "disabled", "disabled"
        else
          $("#add-grade").removeAttr "disabled"
  )
```

html---

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group integer optional grade_student_id"><label class="integer optional control-label" for="grade_student_id">Student</label><div class="controls"><input class="numeric integer optional" id="grade_student_id" name="grade[student_id]" step="1" type="number" /></div></div><br />
    <div class="control-group integer optional grade_lesson_id"><label class="integer optional control-label" for="grade_lesson_id">Lesson</label><div class="controls"><input class="numeric integer optional" id="grade_lesson_id" name="grade[lesson_id]" step="1" type="number" /></div></div><br />
    <div class="control-group select optional grade_score"><label class="select optional control-label" for="grade_score">Score</label><div class="controls"><select autofocus="autofocus" class="select optional" id="grade_score" name="grade[score]"><option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option></select></div></div><br />
    <div class="control-group text optional grade_comment"><label class="text optional control-label" for="grade_comment">Comment</label><div class="controls"><textarea class="text optional" cols="40" id="grade_comment" name="grade[comment]" rows="2"></textarea></div></div>
  <input class="btn" id="add-grade" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Grade" />
</div>
```

Compiled js

```
jQuery(function() {
  return $("#gradesModal :input").on('keypress', function() {
    var empty;
    empty = false;
    return $("#gradesModal :input").each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === "") {
        empty = true;
      }
      if (empty) {
        return $("#add-grade").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      } else {
        return $("#add-grade").removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation is wrong in your CoffeeScript and since CoffeeScript's block structure is based on the indentation, your CoffeeScript is confused. You have three things at the top level; you bind an empty change handler:

```
$("#gradesModal :input").change ->
```

and then you assign to `empty`:

```
empty = false
```

and then finally you iterate over all the `<input>`s inside `#gradesModal`:

```
$("#gradesModal :input").each -> 
  ...
```

The `empty = false` and `.each` are *outside* the `change` handler. Have a look at the JavaScript that your CoffeeScript is turned into and you'll see why it doesn't work.

If you indent things properly so that everything goes inside the `change` handler:

```
$("#gradesModal :input").change ->
  empty = false
  $("#gradesModal :input").each ->
    empty = true if $(this).val() is ""
    if empty
      $("#add-grade").attr "disabled", "disabled"
    else
      $("#add-grade").removeAttr "disabled"
```

then things should start working better.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/j5hCZ/

Or perhaps you mean this:

```
$("#gradesModal :input").change ->
  empty = false
  $("#gradesModal :input").each ->
    empty = true if $(this).val() is ""
  if empty
    $("#add-grade").attr "disabled", "disabled"
  else
    $("#add-grade").removeAttr "disabled"
```

or this:

```
$("#gradesModal :input").change ->
  empty = false
  $("#gradesModal :input").each ->
    empty = true if(!$(this).val())
  if empty
    $("#add-grade").attr "disabled", "disabled"
  else
    $("#add-grade").removeAttr "disabled"
```

Also note that the `change` events from an `<input>` won't be triggered until the `<input>` loses focus so watch out for that too. Switching to `keypress` events might give you a better user experience.

Comment: I've made some changes and it still appears that removing the attribute is still not working.  Would a dropdown cause an issue since it's tagged as <select> and not input? Thanks for your input and the fiddle. Getting in the habit of checking the compiled js is something I need to do.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? What does "not working" mean? Have you stepped through the code with a debugger or added a couple `console.log` calls to watch what it is doing?

Comment: Updated the html.erb to HTML. By not working I mean that it disables on change and then does not remove disabled after the fields are populated. I double checked that the last field loses focus as well. I have debugged with console and it looks like the only thing that's not executing is the "else" part of the conditional.

Comment: Should work fine with a `<select>` in the mix: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/j5hCZ/1/

Comment: Awesome thanks for you help. I'm still having some issues with it but you've helped me narrow it down.  You answered my question about the coffeescript part and that was the main issue. Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE... After working with this for a little bit it looks like the problem was that I was targeting a Modal. When I wrapped the form in a div and targeted the inputs within that div everything started working. Any idea why targeting the modal might cause issues? I assume it's has something to do with why you lose focus on a form within a modal.  I have issues using autofocus on forms within a modal.  They seem to have focus for a split second and then they lose it before the user can type anything. Related maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

To enable

```
$("#add-grade").prop "disabled", true
```

To Disable

```
$("#add-grade").prop "disabled", false
```

Read: [Attributes Vs Properties](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc)